# How to control the order of records for output

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a MASK content element where the editor can choose some records to put out as teasers (see screenshot below). The content should be output in the order selected by the editor. The UID List for example will look like this: 19,18,20,17

In the MySQL syntax the function SELECT FIND_IN_SET() does this job, I think - how can I use it (or a similar functionality) in the select part of a typoscript CONTENT object?

Thank you in advance for any help.

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: My code example - neither the orderBy clause work nor the where clause:

```
table = tt_content
select {
   pidInList = 11,12
   uidInList.data = field:recid  // the list with the wanted record IDs (19,18,20,17) transferred from the content object
   recursive = 2
   join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = tt_content.uid

   orderBy.data = field:recid 
   orderBy.wrap = FIND_IN_SET(`tt_content`.`uid`,'|')

   where = tt_content.CType='mask_cnt_textpic_uni'

   #where.data = field:recid
   #where.wrap = FIND_IN_SET(`tt_content`.`uid`,'|')

   where.data = field:syscats
   where.intval = 1
   where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN (|)

   max = 999
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the note from HerrZ I found the solution - here my customized script:

```
10 = CONTENT
10 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = 11,12
        uidInList.data = field:recid
        recursive = 2
        selectFields.dataWrap = *,FIND_IN_SET(`uid`,'{field:recid}') AS reclist_sortby
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = tt_content.uid
        where = tt_content.CType='mask_cnt_textpic_uni'
        where.data = field:syscats
        where.intval = 1
        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN (|)
        orderBy = reclist_sortby
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj { ... }

}
```

**Important note:** In the FIND_IN_SET syntax, the parameters must be quoted as shown in the example - otherwise Typo3 will throw an error ("Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'").

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

example for content by colPos:

```
lib.content.left = CONTENT
lib.content.left {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=1
    }
}
```

the key here is the select.orderBy

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure if that's the solution for my problem. Can I use the syntax in the brackets as well for FIND_IN_SET and if so, how? My main problem is to output the records **in the order they are passed** (i.e. unsorted). I've add some code above how I've tried to solve the problem, unfortunately without success.

Comment: **20 = CONTENT
 20 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
   pidInList.data = register:pidInList
   selectFields.dataWrap = *,FIND_IN_SET(pid,{register:pidInList}) AS gridelements_shortcut_page_order_by
   where = colPos >= 0
   languageField = sys_language_uid
   orderBy = gridelements_shortcut_page_order_by,colPos,sorting
  }
 }**
thats an example out of a 3rd party extension. there you can find your FIND_IN_SET syntax. please see the order by  to match your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your code example was the hint I needed!